# how to find '|' pattern in string in java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to split string.

for example)

```
str1=str\|2|str3=str4
```

result)

```
str1=str\|2
str3=str4
```

how to split it using pattern in java?

Comment: You have to *escape* `\|`, yes. So, `\\|`.

Comment: Use a negative zero-width lookbehind to exclude the cases with escaped |.

Comment: Not a duplicate: http://ideone.com/6xqT5E The OP is not asking about using "|" in a regex, but allowing escapes in a regex.

Comment: Can an escape be escaped? I.e.: `a=A\\|b=B` becomes `['a=A\\', 'b=B']`

Comment: I used Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\\\][|]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex to split

```
(?<=\\|\\d)\\|
            --
             |
             |->kept | out so it doesnt get included in the result!
```

check it out [here](http://ideone.com/dEAoCX)